# Python problem: opening and closing a file returns a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

Hi guys I've fonund this useful python script that allows me to get some weather data from a site.
I'm going to create a file and the dataset indide.

Something is not working. It returns this error.

```
File "<stdin>", line 42
     f.close()
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What's wrong? In this line I'm only closing the file! 
Could anyone help me please?

This is the python code.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
# Create/open a file called wunder.txt (which will be a comma-delimited file)
f = open('wunder-data.txt', 'w')
# Iterate through year, month, and day
for y in range(1980, 2007):
  for m in range(1, 13):
    for d in range(1, 32):
      # Check if leap year
      if y%400 == 0:
        leap = True
      elif y%100 == 0:
        leap = False
      elif y%4 == 0:
        leap = True
      else:
        leap = False
      # Check if already gone through month
      if (m == 2 and leap and d > 29):
        continue
      elif (m == 2 and d > 28):
        continue
      elif (m in [4, 6, 9, 10] and d > 30):
        continue
      # Open wunderground.com url
      url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/"+str(y)+ "/" + str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/DailyHistory.html"
      page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
      # Get temperature from page
      soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
      dayTemp = soup.body.nobr.b.string
      # Format month for timestamp
      if len(str(m)) < 2:
        mStamp = '0' + str(m)
      else:
        mStamp = str(m)
      # Format day for timestamp
      if len(str(d)) < 2:
        dStamp = '0' + str(d)
      else:
        dStamp = str(d)
      # Build timestamp
      timestamp = str(y) + mStamp + dStamp
      # Write timestamp and temperature to file
      f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')
# Done getting data! Close file.
f.close()
```

Comment: `f.close()` in your code is not at line 42. Be accurate.

Comment: yes, now the code is correct, I deleted the void lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have a whitespace problem in there. Check the whitespace of the file - see where spaces and tabs are. If there are both tabs and spaces in the file, convert them all to spaces.

`f.close` should be at the same indentation level as `f = open('wunder-data.txt', 'w')`

Comment: yes I checked all the whitespaces. The f.close and f open are on the same indent level! What else could be the problem? :(

Comment: When I copy paste your code into a file and run it with Python 2.6 on Windows, no `SyntaxError` is generated. How do you run it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Error showing syntax error in 3.8 just now. And it turns out, my syntax error was a missing closing parenthesis in code above the highlighted line. So, line 42 is not what Question Putter should be looking at. Perhaps, there **is** actually a syntax error somewhere above in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The line with the `f.close()` isn't line 42, so are you sure this is the code that gives the error?

Also, Python seems to process a program received on `stdin`, is this your intention?

Answer (score 0):

Delete lines in your code until the syntax error goes away. Then you'll be able to narrow the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today 2020(October), and I just checked the code above the close() function. I found I hadn't closed a bracket earlier. So the error is in the code above the function and not the actual line specified.

Comment: thank you. I had the same issue. I looked so much to find out what is wrong with the indentation with `f.close()`. This ended up being the `print(....)` incomplete parenthesis in the line before. I wished that Python or Pycharm would have picked it up.