# split a string on the basis of delimeters

Tags: python, string, crop

I have a csv file which comprises of 5 columns of which i need only two columns which are separated by pipe(|) delimiter. Here are few of them:

```
SERIAL_NO|N|1385,45,871,104|1|?
CUST_ID|N|1704,211,552,71|1|?
PROD_TYPE|A|367,286,1167,74|1|?
BRANCH_CODE|N|1892,429,254,74|1|?
BRANCH_NAME|A|682,412,774,72|1|?
DATE|N|2022,581,241,82-1863,581,137,75-1697,581,153,85|1|?
```

I want just the 0th and 2nd index data in a list so that i can feed that data to a image on the basis of given coordinates i am going to do cropping in image and save those images with file name same as the 0th index data.

In order to make it more clear here is what i want to do i have a image whose coordinates are in csv file (like this 1385,45,871,104) and after cropping on the basis of given coordinates i want to save file with the name of 0th index data of that row which is(SERIAL_NO).i have to do that for all the rows and some rows have more than one coordinates which was divided by - symbol.

Comment: Please stop using the `opencv` and `image-processing` tags for this kind of questions! It's more than clear from your now four quite identical questions, what you want to achieve in the end. Nevertheless, this single problem stated here - by itself - has nothing to do with OpenCV or image processing. Also, don't ignore answers to [your prior question(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55914332/).

Comment: @HansHirse the solution in prior problem is not working....

Comment: Then post a comment on that answer there, and continue there! Don't open nearly identical questions within short time, repeatedly using wrong tags. For example, you didn't reply to the answerer's last comment in your prior question.

Comment: And when writing questions, and especially titles, please leave out all the fluff like "I was having trouble while", "I want to know how to" and focus on the actual issue you have.

Comment: @JamesZ@HansHirse How to Crop images on the basis of those coordinates which is in format of (x,y,w,h) and save the cropped images with column one(that SERIAL_NO,CUST_ID and so on) names.I Basically want to save all the snippets in respective folders and Draw all the region coordinates available in csv file and save the file with naming conventions. Field name as the file name

Comment: Please don't ask additional questions in comments. Just create a new question, and you can of course mention this question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open("file.csv", "r")
coordinates = []
for line in f:
    splitted = line.split("|")
    for coor in splitted[2].split("-"):
        coordinates.append((splitted[0], coor)
f.close()
```

This should give you coordinates as a list of tupels.

Comment: i am getting error....... f = open("page1_CA.csv", "r")
coordinates = []
for line in f:
    splitted = line.split("|")
    for coor in splitted[2].split("-"):
        coordinates.append((splitted[0], coor)

f.close()
  File "<ipython-input-131-98c21d0727f3>", line 8
    f.close()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you should have a look at your indents: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045605/python-problem-opening-and-closing-a-file-returns-a-syntax-error

Comment: How to Crop images on the basis of those coordinates which is in format of (x,y,w,h) and save the cropped images with column one(that SERIAL_NO,CUST_ID and so on) names.I Basically want to save all the snippets in respective folders and Draw all the region coordinates available in csv file and save the file with naming conventions. Field name as the file name

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `csv` module to split the file up for you on pipe characters:

```
import csv
f = open("file.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
for row in reader:
    print (row[0],":",row[2].split("-"))
```

Output is

```
SERIAL_NO : ['1385,45,871,104']
CUST_ID : ['1704,211,552,71']
PROD_TYPE : ['367,286,1167,74']
BRANCH_CODE : ['1892,429,254,74']
BRANCH_NAME : ['682,412,774,72']
DATE : ['2022,581,241,82', '1863,581,137,75', '1697,581,153,85']
```

Comment: as you can see in date row there are three different coordinates i want them also individually....

Comment: I don't believe that was in your problem statement. You said that there could be more than one set of coordinates, not what you wanted done with them. But I've done an edit on the question. You can't get `csv` to pay attention to 2 delimiters at once so you have to do the second level of splitting yourself.

Comment: How to Crop images on the basis of those coordinates which is in format of (x,y,w,h) and save the cropped images with column one(that SERIAL_NO,CUST_ID and so on) names.I Basically want to save all the snippets in respective folders and Draw all the region coordinates available in csv file and save the file with naming conventions. Field name as the file name